# Create a SharePoint page that is mobile friendly

Tags: custom-masterpage, features, mobile-view

I have a SharePoint 2013 site hosted by a third party (so, no access to web.config). I am building a mobile app to use specific pages from the site. I am currently getting errors redirecting my pages to  '/_layouts/mobile/mbllists.aspx' because SharePoint detects that I am using a mobile device. I can disable the Mobile Browser View feature as outlined here [https://academy.bindtuning.com/deactivate-sharepoint-2013-mobile-view](https://academy.bindtuning.com/deactivate-sharepoint-2013-mobile-view/), but I don't want to turn it off for the whole site.

All I want is to build a handful of pages that SharePoint accepts as mobile-friendly and doesn't try to redirect. I already have a Master Page I am using for these pages, to get around the Frames issue. So, what code can I put in the Master Page or on the individual pages to tell SharePoint to leave them alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to build a "mobile" subsite and put all of my pages there. I then disable the Mobile Browser View feature for the subsite. Since the references to my lists are in code, I can consume the lists from the parent site. Plus, I don't have to change the look and feel of the parent site.